# Applying for a Schengen visa with a valid US student visa and an expired I-20 form

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, schengen-visas

I have a valid F1 visa, but my I-20 and opt have expired. My H1-B application got selected in the lottery and I am eligible to stay in the US under capgap.

Now however, for personal reasons, I need to move back to India before October 1st and I am planning to take a trip around Europe on my way back. What may be the complications in getting a Schengen visa?

Comment: Are you a citizen of India? Any other citizenships?

Comment: Yes.. I am an Indian citizen.. I do not hold any other citizenships.

Comment: On your way back to India or on your way back to the US from India?

Comment: Your F-1 or H-1B makes no difference except for transit through Europe.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, having an expired I-20 would make it impossible for you to apply for a tourist Schengen visa in the US. Local Schengen consulates ask for a valid I-20 in order to verify that you are a long-term resident. For example, here are the [residency requirements](http://www.consulfrance-washington.org/spip.php?article384) of the French consulate in the US:

> **For non American citizens**, a proof of resident status in the USA (green card, **valid US visa and copy of valid I-20 or valid I-AP66**, visas...). The visa AND the US resident status must be still valid at least 3 months after the last day of stay in the Schengen area (+ one copy of the visa, green card or relevant document). US pre-approval notices for US visas will be declined (only valid US visas affixed in your passport are accepted).

The Greek consulate has [similar requirements](http://www.mfa.gr/usa/en/services/services-for-non-greeks/visa-section.html):

> For foreign students on F1 visas:
>
> - **valid I-20**
> - reference letter from educational institution (school/college/university)   stating that you are in good standing, your major and the expected date of graduation.

You can still transit through the Schengen area if your visa [satisfies the conditions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area) of visa-free transit.

Comment: If I am not mistake a valid US visa is accepted at some Schengen states in lieu of a transit visa if the traveler is going to/from the US; so depending on the itinerary the person may not need a transit visa.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid but OP wants to take a trip, not just transit.

Comment: I was referring to your last line _"You can still apply for a transit visa"_

Comment: @BurhanKhalid answer updated.